# How to get disk GUID using drive letter from a Windows command script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm looking to be able to supply a drive letter and get back the disk GUID within a Windows command script.  From the command line I can do the following but I am not sure how to script this:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk #
uniqueid disk
```

The closest I could find was this snippet that pulls the volume number based on the drive letter but I believe there would need to be a nested loop to select each of the disks and I can't figure out how to incorporate that:

```
for /f "tokens=2,3" %%a in ('echo list volume ^| diskpart') do (
    if %%b==%driveletter% (
        echo Volume number is %%a
    )
)
```

Also since `list disk` doesn't specify the volume letters there would need to be something translating the disk # to the volume #, is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides `select volume 1`, you can also use `select volume C` or `selct volume C:` (note the response mentions the corresponding volume *number*).
Also you don't have to find and select the corresponding disk manually. `Uniqueid disk` translates the selected volume to the disk.

This makes it quite easy:

```
@echo off 
setlocal
set "Drive=C:"
for /f "tokens=2 delims={}" %%a in ('(echo select volume %Drive%^&echo uniqueid disk^)^|diskpart') do set "GUID=%%a"
echo Disk GUID for %Drive% is %guid%
```

Based on the [discussion with Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66693118/2152082), I adapted the `for` loop to take care of the different output with MBR vs. GPT drives:

```
@echo off 
setlocal
set "Drive=C:"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('(echo select volume %Drive%^&echo uniqueid disk^)^|diskpart^|find ":"') do (
  for %%b in (%%a) do set "GUID=%%b"
)
echo Disk GUID for %Drive% is %guid%
```

With this change, the output format now looks either like:

```
Disk GUID for C: is {DC8DD71C-31B8-4B04-9FB6-C66A325B738B}
```

or like:

```
Disk GUID for F: is DB72E293
```

Comment: I did put this in a `.bat` file and run it. It asks for UAC, then a separate window appears with diskpart. Nothing more happens. Script output is: `Disk GUID for C: is`

Comment: @MatthiasRonge: You have to run the script "as administrator". Only then the interactive mode of `diskpart` works. Else it opens a new window "as administrator" (as you noticed), invalidating the code.